# Conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried converting the `YYYYMMDD` to `MM/DD/YY` and used the code below, but didn't work:

```
Convert(Varchar(8),Convert(Datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),s.birth_date)),101) DOB
```

Can someone assist me.

Comment: what's the original data type of `birth_date`?, why are you converting it to varchar, then datetime, then varchar again?

Comment: The original data type is Int.

Comment: And you want the result as varchar?!?

Comment: well, then you probably have values there that can't be converted to datetime

Comment: I was thinking of same, so what would be the best bet ?

Comment: to take a look at your data?

Comment: I would test going from INT to VARCHAR which shouldn't have a problem look at the output then convert it to DATE with the 101 format. Unless you have to have the time I wouldn't worry about it that could be the problem.

Comment: [The best solution would be to store dates as dates and not as ints...](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: i know what you mean Zohar, but this is how its been setup, and i dont have any privileges to update those at this moment.

Comment: @Engin, it works when you pass the certain date value ( 20160307), but my table contains the date stored with INT datatype. And it throws me an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  birth_date As IntDate,  
            LEFT(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 4) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 5, 2) +'-'+ RIGHT(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 2) As ISOFormat,
            SUBSTRING(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 5, 2) +'/'+ RIGHT(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 2) +'/'+ LEFT(CAST(birth_date as char(8)), 4) As USFormat
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE birth_date > 9999999 -- must have 8 digits
    AND birth_date < 99991232 -- last supported date is 9999-12-31
)

SELECT IntDate, ISOFormat, USFormat
FROM CTE 
WHERE ISDATE(ISOFormat) = 1
```

Comment: Glad to help. Btw, If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know the problem is solved